# The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to retrieve product name and its ids as NameID object from EntityFramework using WebAPI. code for which is as following.

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    protected MainDataContext db = new MainDataContext();
    // GET /api/values
    public IQueryable<NameID> Get()
    {
        return db.Products.Select(x=>new NameID{ ID=x.ID,Name=x.Name }).AsQueryable();
    }

    // GET /api/values/5
    public NameID Get(long id)
    {
        var result = db.Products.Select(x=>new NameID{ ID=x.ID,Name=x.Name }).SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
        if (id == 0 || result == null)
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound); 
        return result;
    }

}
public class NameID {
    public long ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

It throws error as following

```
The magic number in GZip header is not correct.
Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.

at System.IO.Compression.GZipDecoder.ReadHeader(InputBuffer input) 
at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Decode() 
at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Inflate(Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, Int32 length) 
at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count) 
at System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count) 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InitStreamInput(Uri baseUri, String baseUriStr, Stream stream, Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteCount, Encoding encoding) 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(Stream stream, Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteCount, XmlReaderSettings settings, Uri baseUri, String baseUriStr, XmlParserContext context, Boolean closeInput) 
at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(Stream input, Uri baseUri, String baseUriString, XmlParserContext inputContext) 
at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(Stream input, XmlReaderSettings settings, String baseUri) 
at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(Stream stream, LoadOptions options) 
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Edm.ModelCompressor.Decompress(Byte[] bytes) 
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.GetLastModel(String& migrationId) 
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.GetLastModel() 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.QueryForModel() 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.ModelCompatibilityChecker.CompatibleWithModel(InternalContext internalContext, ModelHashCalculator modelHashCalculator, Boolean throwIfNoMetadata) 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata) 
at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClass8.<PerformDatabaseInitialization>b__6() 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() 
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() 
at System.Linq.Queryable.Select[TSource,TResult](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 selector) 
at ProductAPI.Controllers.ProductController.Get() in D:\Demo\ProductAPI\Controllers\ProductController.cs:line 24 
at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] ) 
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments) 
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.Execute(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments) 
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass2.<InvokeActionAsync>b__0() 
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: are you trying to unzip .zip file with gzip?

Comment: I am not trying anything. except returning NameID object. and this is pure Vannila Project with EntityFramework poco. No http Compression set either.

Comment: In case it help it doesn't error on returing of IQueryable. I am modifying the code to explain further.

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems that EF is trying to retrieve model metadata from the database and this metadata is corrupted (not in GZip format as expected). Have you tried to recreate the database?

Comment: I just see the metadata is currupted. thanks @MartinLiversage that helped.

Comment: Please delete the question or post an answer if your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The stack trace seems to indicate the there is a problem reading the Entity Framework model metadata from the database.

`HistoryRepository.GetLastModel` calls `ModelCompressor.Decompress` that uses `XDocument.Load` to read some XML from a `GZipStream`. This fails and the model metadata in the database is most likely corrupted.

You can try to recreate the database to get around this problem.

Answer (score 6):

Its a little late and there is already an accepted answer, which will work. But, if you already have a working database and do not want to refresh the database, then you can call `Database.SetInitializer` with null in Global.asax's application_start function. This will not looking for the `__migrationhistory` table that contains the corrupt data.

Answer (score 4):

No way to recreate the database for me and I am already using `Database.SetInitializer` with `null`.

Fortunately, I have an up-to-date `__MigrationHistory` table on another database and I used this Sql query to set the correct value in the target database :

```
INSERT INTO TargetDbName.dbo.__MigrationHistory (MigrationId, Model, ProductVersion)
SELECT MigrationId, Model, ProductVersion
FROM SourceDbName.dbo.__MigrationHistory
WHERE MigrationId = 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSSFFF_LastMigration'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solution worked for me. I was struggling with this since two days and the error message was too misleading but finally google brought me to this solution. My Code First DB was not accessible from visual studio and no migration was possible. I copied all content for DB but it did not work. However setting the null value for the above property in Global.asax.cs worked for me

Comment: I have a similar issue, I have 3 migrations that I need to add and they don't exist in another database. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got rid of this error by running the database migration using **UPDATE-DATABASE**. It ran all the migration files, created the migration history table as well as the model's hash value.

To give you an idea of what happened earlier: I previously ran the migration script in Dev environment and copied the migration history data from Production. Whenever I run my Web API, EF reads the database and finds the database context not synced with specs that is in migration history table.

After I ran the UPDATE-DATABASE, everything went well.