# The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing a GZip stream

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, entity-framework, io

I'm working in a WinForm App with Mysql db, so when I ran the db script on MySql Workbench displays this msg

[image]

I clicked 'OK'and displays the script

[image]

after Run the script and create the db, when I run my WinForm App displays this exception at the first query to the db:

```
var permissions_in_db = db.Permissions
                            .Where(a => a.Name == s)
                            .Count();
```

**System.IO.InvalidDataException not be controlled : "The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing a GZip stream."**

Here's the trace

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException not be controlled
  HResult = -2146233087
  Message = The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing a GZip stream.
  Source = System
  StackTrace :
       in System.IO.Compression.GZipDecoder.ReadHeader ( InputBuffer input)
       in System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Decode ( )
       in System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Inflate ( Byte [ ] bytes , Int32 offset , Int32 length)
       in System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Read ( Byte [ ] array , Int32 offset , Int32 count)
       in System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.Read ( Byte [ ] array , Int32 offset , Int32 count)
       in System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InitStreamInput ( baseUri Uri , String baseUriStr , Stream stream , Byte [ ] bytes , Int32 byteCount , Encoding encoding)
       in System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishInitStream ( )
       in System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader (Stream input , baseUri Uri , String baseUriString , XmlParserContext inputContext )
       in System.Xml.XmlReader.Create (Stream input , XmlReaderSettings settings , String baseUri )
       in System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load (Stream stream, LoadOptions options)
       in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Edm.ModelCompressor.Decompress ( Byte [ ] bytes )
       in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.GetLastModel (String & migrationId )
       in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.GetLastModel ( )
       in System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.QueryForModel ( )
       in System.Data.Entity.Internal.ModelCompatibilityChecker.CompatibleWithModel ( InternalContext internalContext , ModelHashCalculator modelHashCalculator , Boolean throwIfNoMetadata )
       in System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel (Boolean throwIfNoMetadata )
       in System.Data.Entity.Database.CompatibleWithModel (Boolean throwIfNoMetadata )
       in System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges ` 1.InitializeDatabase ( tcontext context)
       in System.Data.Entity.Database . < > c__DisplayClass2 ` 1. <SetInitializerInternal> b__0 ( DbContext c )
       in System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext . < > c__DisplayClass8 . <PerformDatabaseInitialization> b__6 ( )
       in System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction ( Action action)
       in System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization ( )
       in System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext . <InitializeDatabase> b__4 ( InternalContext c )
       in System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction ` 1.PerformAction ( TInput input)
       in System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction ( Action ` 1 action )
       in System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase ( )
       in System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize ( )
       in System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType (Type entityType )
       in System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet 1.Initialize ` ( )
       in System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet 1.get_InternalContext ` ( )
       in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery 1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider ` ( )
       in System.Linq.Queryable.Where [ TSource ] (IQueryable ` 1 source , Expression ` 1 predicate )
       in RoleCreatorV5_net4.Login.button1_Click (Object sender, EventArgs e) in c: \ Users \ Rafa \ Downloads \ 1 \ final versions \ RoleCreatorV5_net4 \ Login.cs : line 30
       in System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp ( MouseEventArgs mevent )
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp (Message & m , MouseButtons button , Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (Message & m )
       in System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc (Message & m )
       in System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc (Message & m )
       in System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback (IntPtr hWnd , Int32 msg , IntPtr wparam , IntPtr lparam )
       in System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW (MSG & msg)
       in System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID , Int32 reason , Int32 pvLoopData )
       in System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner (Int32 reason , ApplicationContext context)
       in System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop (Int32 reason , ApplicationContext context)
       in RoleCreatorV5_net4.Program.Main () in c: \ Users \ Rafa \ Downloads \ 1 \ final versions \ RoleCreatorV5_net4 \ Program.cs : line 70
       in System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly ( RuntimeAssembly assembly, String [ ] args)
       in System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance ( ActivationContext activationContext , String [ ] activationCustomData )
       in Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone ( )
       in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal ( ExecutionContext executionContext , ContextCallback callback , Object state , Boolean preserveSyncCtx )
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run ( ExecutionContext executionContext , ContextCallback callback , Object state , Boolean preserveSyncCtx )
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run ( ExecutionContext executionContext , ContextCallback callback , Object state )
       in System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart ( )
  InnerException :
```

Here is the code from the Program.cs

```
[STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {

            Database.SetInitializer<MySqlContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MySqlContext>());


            var connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ToString();

            using (var db = new MySqlContext())
            {

                #region Load CheckedList1

                const string f = "/Users/Rafa/Documents/Proyecto NS/SavedList.txt";
                List<string> lines = new List<string>();
                using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        lines.Add(line);
                    }
                }

                foreach (string s in lines)
                {

                    var permissions_in_db = db.Permissions
                        .Where(a => a.Name == s)
                        .Count();
                    if (permissions_in_db < 1)
                    {
                        if (s!="")
                        {
                            db.Permissions.AddOrUpdate(new Permission
                            {
                                Name = s
                            });
                            db.SaveChanges();    
                        }

                    }
                }
                #endregion

                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Login());
        }
    }
```

I really hope someone can help me!

Comment: Have you tried changing the encoding of the sql file to a compatible version before trying to run the script?

Comment: `const string f = "/Downloads/SavedList.txt";` your slashes are facing the wrong direction

Comment: Also... if you did switch the slashes `\Downloads\SavedList.txt` isn't even a valid path.

Comment: Already edit the path (check my edit) and I have changed the encode to LATIN1 before to run my script and still does not work... how to know wich is the compatible encode? @OhaxNuv

Comment: Your path is still invalid `/Users/Rafa/Documents/Proyecto NS/SavedList.txt` is not right, you would have to to do `@"C:\Users\Rafa\Documents\Proyecto NS\SavedList.txt"` did you debug through to see if your `lines` object is being populated?

Comment: yes, the lines are populated and still I get the same exception when i query the db @OhaxNuv

Comment: what line of code does it crash on?

Comment: here i found this for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087508/the-magic-number-in-gzip-header-is-not-correct-make-sure-you-are-passing-in-a-g

Comment: I'll re create the db @OhaxNuv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is some data in __migrationhistory Model column, latin encoding messes up the data. To rescue, run the script without opening the file. With new MySql Workbench, there is a button "Run SQL Script" which allows you to run without specifying encoding.
[image]